# Data View Web Part sorting across pagination

Tags: web-part

Sorting in data view web part(when enabling the checkbox in properties) works for the rows which are currently displayed, but i want that all the rows across apgination gets sorted. What modifications i need to do in XSLT or please suggest any other alternative. Please reply ASAP, its very urgent for me. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection" DefaultValue="Modified"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"  DefaultValue="descending"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sumit.
But you know it very well that, then pagination numbering issue comes up :)